# Accessing a variable declared outside a class from inside the class

Tags: python

I have a stupid question. I guess I do not understand variable scope in python.

I have the following code.

```
#!/bin/python

class Test:
    def Inc(self):
         Count = Count + 1
         print 'Count = ' + str(Count)

class Test2:
    def Dec(self):
         Count = Count - 1
         print 'Count = ' + str(Count)


def main():
    t = Test()
    t2 = Test2()
    t.Inc()
    t2.Dec()

if  __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Is there a way to declare and use Count the way I am doing?

The way I did above does not work, I get the following error -

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Count' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Where have you initialized `Count`?

Comment: Should I not? Where should I initialize it? in main()? I guess its a really awful question that people downvoted it, though I am ignorant to even understand why :)

Comment: @user220201 "Where should I initialize it?" in the `__init__` member function of the class.

Comment: @user220201 Perhaps if you tell us what exactly you are trying to do, we can resolve this problem easily.

Comment: It's not very likely your Python binary is in /bin. You probably man `#!/usr/bin/env python` or at least `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: @starrify - I want to declare it outside the class. Declaring/Initializing it in the __init__ of the class will make a static variable in the class. I want it to be outside because I might want to access it from a Test2 class I might need in the same file.

Comment: @MikeGraham - You are right. Its in /usr/bin/.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 Count = 0

 class Test:
    def Inc(self):
         global Count
         Count = Count + 1
```

You have to declare you are using the global version. If you want an instance variable do this...

```
def Inc(self):
     self.count = ...
```

Comment: I had no idea till now that the keyword global exists in python. Thanks! I will read up more on it. It seems to be the one I am looking for. Is there a reason why I might not want to use it?

Comment: Why would you use a class to simply increment a global variable?

Comment: The question is about accessing that variable inside the class. We don't know if he is actually doing more in that class that he just hasn't posted here.

Answer (score 2):

You got your error because you use `Count` (in the expression `Count + 1`) before you ever said what Count was.

You probably want something like

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def inc(self):
        self.count = self.count + 1 # or self.count += 1
        print 'Count = ' + str(self.count)

def main():
    t = Test()
    t.inc()

if  __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please see the edit to the question. I have two classes that I want to use Count from

Answer (score 0):

`Count` is a local variable, created every time `Inc` is called, and discarded on return. What you want is an instance attribute. To make an instance attribute, it needs to be bound to `self`, like this:

```
def Inc(self):
    self.Count = self.Count + 1
    print 'Count = ' + str(Count)
```

**But wait!** `self.Count + 1` can't be evaluated, because `self.Count` doesn't exist yet! So in your `__init__` (which you're about to define), set it to `0`:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Count = 0

    def Inc(self):
        self.Count = self.Count + 1
        print 'Count = ' + str(Count)
```

Lastly, it's customary to start function and variable names with lowercase, leaving uppercase for class names. So change everything to the following:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def inc(self):
        self.count = self.count + 1
        print 'count = ' + str(count)

def main():
    t = Test()
    t.inc()
```

To access it outside the class, use this:

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.inc()
>>> print t.count
1
```

Comment: @user220201, you're moving the goal post here... but that being said do your methods actually need to be in different classes? Or does it make more sense to put them both in `Test`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was trying to make the question as simple as possible but did not realize I led people in the wrong direction. Its just an example. I need the variable to be outside the classes.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way: not the right way to do but according to your question:

```
Count = 0

class Test:
    def Inc(self):
        Count = globals()['Count']
        Count = Count + 1
        print 'Count = ' + str(Count)

def main():
    t = Test()
    t.Inc()

if  __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Count is adding 1 to itself. However, it doesn't know what it is since you've never initialised it.

```
class Test:
   def __init__(self):
      self._count = 0     #Starting point

   def Inc(self):
       self._count = self._count + 1
       print 'Count = ' + str(self._count)
```

Edited to match comments:

```
class Test:
   def __init__(self, c):
      self._count = c

   def inc(self):
       self._count = self._count + 1
```

Then from main() or wherever:

```
c = 0
t = Test(c)
t.inc()
```

Comment: Please see the edit to the question. I have two classes and I want to use Count from function in either one of the classes

Comment: Ah. you're opening a can of worms. You're going to need to consider the use case, e.g. do you need thread safety? If not then simplest is to pass "Count" to both classes as a constructor parameter.

Comment: awesome idea. I need not worry about threading issues as well in that case. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest:

```
class CallCount(object):
    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self.count=start
    def __call__(self):
        self.count+=1
        return self.count
```

Then use it this way:

```
>>> c=CallCount()
>>> c()
1
>>> c()
2
>>> c()
3
```

Comment: How is this different from using the global keyword as jeremy suggested above?

Comment: Depend if you want the interface to be a call type or incrementing an attribute.

Comment: "Accessing a variable declared outside a class" it doesn't answer his question to have him reinitialize the variable in the constructor.